# How to use routing for auth0_flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, auth0

I"m trying to integrate auto0 into my Flutter application. I want to know how to use routing because when I try routing like this I’m not getting a callback for a user who is successfully logged in. I’m using auto_route for routing. My Main. dart is looking like this

My main. dart is looking like this

```
`
  Future<void> main() async {
    setupLocator();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await dotenv.load();
    await ApplicationPreference().initData();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  Auth0Web auth0Web =
       Auth0Web(dotenv.env['AUTH0_DOMAIN']!, dotenv.env['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID']!);

  runApp(MyApp(auth0Web: auth0Web));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Auth0Web auth0Web;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.auth0Web}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerDelegate: locator<AppRouter>().delegate(
        initialRoutes: [LoginRoute(auth0Web: auth0Web)],
      ),
      routeInformationParser: locator<AppRouter>().defaultRouteParser(),
    );
  }
}`
```

```
// My login screen where user is try to log in
``class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  final  Auth0Web auth0Web;
  const Login({final Key? key, required this.auth0Web}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _ExampleAppState();
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<Login> {
  late WebAuthentication webAuth;
  late Auth0Web auth0Web;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth0Web =
        Auth0Web(dotenv.env['AUTH0_DOMAIN']!, dotenv.env['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID']!);

    auth0Web.onLoad().then((final credentials) {
      print("on load");
      if (credentials != null) {
        ApplicationPreference.instanceShared.saveLoggedIn(true);
        print("on load not null ");
      } else {
        ApplicationPreference.instanceShared.saveLoggedIn(false);
        print("on load null ");
      }
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    Utils.deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    Utils.deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
        body: ApplicationPreference().getUserLoggedIn()
            ? const Dashboard()
            : Center(child:Text("logged in")));
  }
  

  Future<void> webAuthLogin() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    // We also handle the message potentially returning null.
    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        return auth0Web.loginWithRedirect(redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000');
      }

      final result = await webAuth.login();
    } catch (e) {
       if (kDebugMode) {
         print("auth error ${e`your text`.toString()}");
       }
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
  }
}``
```